# Temporary table in where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need some records from Temporary table and for this I am trying to run following query:

```
DECLARE @temp_table TABLE (Id uniqueidentifier, Dates nvarchar(10))

INSERT @temp_table
SELECT ID,Right(Companies.UserDefined4, 10)
FROM   Companies

Select *
From  Companies,@temp_table
Where Companies.ID = @temp_table.Id
```

But in `Where` clause I am getting this error:

> The scalar variable @temp_table must be declared.

Comment: You need to give it an alias and use the alias. Also please use a proper `INNER JOIN`. So `FROM dbo.Companies AS c INNER JOIN @temp_table AS t ON c.ID = t.Id;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct code should be like :

```
DECLARE @temp_table TABLE (Id uniqueidentifier, Dates nvarchar(10))

INSERT @temp_table
SELECT ID,Right(Companies.UserDefined4, 10)
FROM   Companies

Select *
From  Companies c
join @temp_table t
  on c.ID = t.Id
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
SELECT *
FROM Companies c
INNER JOIN @temp_table t ON c.ID = t.ID
```